# Advangates of using addAccount over exporting LoginActivity in another app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-account

Context:

Suppose we have two Android apps installed, A that contains a custom Authenticator code and can add new accounts to AccountManager, and B that we want to have single-touch sign in flow. You can assume the account has not yet been created in AccountManager by A.

Question:

From the perspective of B, what are the advantages of using AccountManager's addAccount method, which would require declaring `android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS` in the AndroidManifest of the B) over `exporting the LoginActivity` from the A app, and simply calling it via an intent, to create that account for B. Naturally, A already declares all required permissions. If you think the latter solution is actually better (because we don't need to declare yet another permission), I would also like to know, if you have something interesting to say to support your opinion.

You can assume I don't need to protect LoginActivity with a permission, although it is exported, because the only side effect it has is creating the account in AccountManager, which is exactly what we need.

Misc:

To give more context, if this helps answering my question:

- in case A is not installed, B falls back to its own sign in form (but does not act as an authenticator and does not create an account, the retrieved OAuth token is only used by B)
- B does declare INTERNET permission
- both A and B are signed with the same release key
- A and B do not share android:sharedUserId

Comment: If both apps have to full ability for authorisation what is the benifit?

Comment: The benefit is you don't have to input your username and password more than once, if you use A to sign in :) Also, any other app can leverage AccountManager to use that account.

This is one of the reasons B would ask A for sign in, rather than immediately handle sign in on its own (even though it has that feature), because only A can create an account in AccountManager.

The benefit is single sign on to both (and possibly more) apps.

Comment: I see. Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand it is a good idea to have an app with almost no permissions on the other hand this is some kind of cheating to use a second app for communication with the internet.

IMHO it is very important that you have a plan in case your `AccountManager` app gets uninstalled. In this case you have a big problem, depending on your authorisation process.

However with the [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) you can see if both apps are installed.

---

It's a good idea to make the other app optional. If both apps have at minimum the internet permission it won't make the impression of cloaking the communication. A special permission whould have the benefit that no other app can use your *public* API/intent. I don't know your design and if this could be a problem. However even if you use a seperat permission a malicious app could also ask for that permission.

Comment: Hi rekire! Thanks for your feedback. This is why I started with "Suppose we have two Android apps installed". To clarify, I edited my question to include the info that B can handle sign in, even if A is not installed at all. And yes, I use PackageManager to verify that :)

Comment: "I don't know your design and if this could be a problem." -- it is not the problem, because the LoginActivity of A only creates the account as a side effect, B still has to ask AccountManager for the token, thus -- any app that would invoke the exported activity would still require GET_ACCOUNTS and USE_CREDENTIALS permissions.

Comment: In this case I see no problems.

Comment: Cool, so exporting the LoginActivity seems a viable option. Thank you for your opinion, I'll leave the question open so others can chime in :)

Comment: @karni you should still accept the answer if it answered your question though. Others can still answer .

Comment: @Deanna Thank you for the hint. The author of the answer states what I already know and 'sees no problems'. That is not, in my reception, what would constitute an answer. This is the reason why I haven't accepted it, as I would highly value any further feedback on my question. Thanks!

Comment: Well I would like to get 15 rep ;-)